# Inline-Block Pushing elements down

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to create list items that highlight when hovered but when I use inline, it works where the list items are horizontally next to each other but when I use inline block (so I can set height and width), they get pushed vertically below each other.

Can anyone find my issue?

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Master.css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="navBar">
    <img id="imgLogo" src="Images/logo_netflix.png" />
    <ul id="navBarRight">
        <li id="liLogin" class="navItem"><a runat="server" href="Account/Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
        <li id="liRegister" class="navItem"><a runat="server" href="Account/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
/* Universal */
body {
font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
background-color: #DEDEDE;
margin: 0px;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
div#navBar{
height: 50px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #000000;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
}
#imgLogo{
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
ul#navBarRight{
height: 50px;
width: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline;
float: right;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
li.navItem{
display: inline-block;
color: black;
list-style-type: none;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
li:hover{
background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `width: 100%` in the class .navItem.

Comment: It was the width. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using float instead of inline or inline block. https://jsfiddle.net/37oseq80/2/

```
ul#navBarRight{
  border:1px solid;
  width:500px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: right;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
li.navItem{
float:right;
color: black;
list-style-type: none;
height: 100%;
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

And ofcourse dont forget use clear:both after the last child of the ul.

Answer (score 0):

You have `width: 100%` in the CSS rule for `li.navItem`- that way the nav items will take the whole width of the parent element and get placed *below* each other as you describe.

Make that width smaller - try 20% (or a fixed pixel value) as a beginning and then gradually change it until it looks the way you want.